# How to generate ZIP file of S3 files in Meteor

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, zip, jszip

I'm trying to find a way of allowing a user in my Meteor app to click a button and download multiple files that they have access to (that are stored in S3 using the Slingshot package).

My first idea was just to open each file in a new tab in the browser but quickly seeing that some browsers won't allow for multiple new tabs being opened and see them as popups.

I've seen the JSZip package and I think I understand how to create a ZIP file OK using basic text inserts

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
var img = zip.folder("images");
img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});
var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
```

but I'm less sure on how to generate a ZIP file of the various S3 urls I pass it.

Does anyone have any pointers either to how to add these remote files to the ZIP or perhaps even allow browsers to allow multiple downloads?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Meteor supports npm packages and you can use `s3-zip` package for downloading zip of a set of files.

Sample use:

```
var s3Zip = require('s3-zip');
var fs = require('fs');

var region = 'bucket-region';
var bucket = 'name-of-s3-bucket';
var folder = 'name-of-bucket-folder/';
var file1 = 'Image A.png';
var file2 = 'Image B.png';
var file3 = 'Image C.png';
var file4 = 'Image D.png';

var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/use-s3-zip.zip');

s3Zip
  .archive({ region: region, bucket: bucket}, folder, [file1, file2, file3, file4])
  .pipe(output);
```

Link to this package: [s3-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-zip)

Additional resouces:

1. [Installing npm package in Meteor](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#installing-npm)
2. [Using npm package in Meteor](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#using-npm)

Using npm packages directly will work for meteor 1.3 and above. For lower versions use [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm)